# How to use Sed to replace specific characters

Tags: bash, sed

How to use **Sed** to replace all **bold** characters? (for example from 0200 to 0300)

*the whole command is in one line*

> NSun**0000**-0000Mon**0200**+2130Tue**0200**+2130Wed**0200**+2130Thu**0200**+2130Fri**0200**+2130Sat**0000**-0000

This must be a universal command because the digits can change (but will always be in the same place).

Comment: post expected output for entire sample for clarity.. what should `0000` be changed to? and more importantly, add what you've tried to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Bash and you want to change each one to 0300.

```
ubuntu$ sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{4})/\10300/g' text.txt
NSun0300-0000Mon0300+2130Tue0300+2130Wed0300+2130Thu0300+2130Fri0300+2130Sat0300-0000
```

Regards!

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually the output looks like this: NSun030-0000Mon030+2130Tue030+2130Wed030+2130Thu030+2130Fri030+2130Sat030-0000 cuts one digit too much

Comment: Im not getting that output here. Can you paste the exact output you are getting along with the input file you are using?